# Laravel 5: Eloquent select + with returns error 502 on nginx/apache

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, eloquent

I have the following request:

```
            $orders = OrderHeader
            ->with('status')
            ->select('id')
            ->get();
```

And it returns 502 Bad gateway on nginx+php-fpm and ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE on apache2.

If I remove either 'with' or 'select' everything works good.

I've already performed the regular operations such as restarting nginx and php-fpm, reinstalling the php-fpm, changing some fastcgi parameters in nginx config - all these actions didn't help.

The nginx error log shows '104 Connection reset by peer' and there's nothing in php log.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that what you really want is this:

```
$orders = OrderHeader->with('status')->lists('id');
```

No need to try to select the column off of the table. If for some reason you need more control, then use a `closure` to filter the query accordingly:

```
$orders = OrderHeader->with(['status' => function($query){
    return $query->select('id');
}])->get();
```

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for help. In the database each order header has a corresponding status object. As a result of query, I want to have the order id with its status joined. So the order id field and the status object should both be included in the result. Thus, I think your solution is a bit different.